# Non scalable unit in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, scale

Is there a non scalable unit in tikz?

I have the following picture,

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, scale=2]
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,1);
    \filldraw   (0,0) circle[radius=0.05cm] node[anchor=north] {$P$}
                (2,1) circle[radius=0.05cm] node[anchor=north] {$Q$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Some elements, like the line width, the arrowheads or the text aren't affected by the `scale=2` option. I would like the circles to behave in the same fashion. Is this possible? I tried using different units for the circle radius `(cm, pt, em)` but I had no luck.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use a node instead of a circle. nodes don't scale either:

```
 \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, scale=2]
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,1);
    \filldraw   (0,0) node[circle,inner sep=0.025cm,fill=black]{} node[anchor=north] {$P$}
                (2,1) circle[radius=0.05cm] node[anchor=north] {$Q$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason why you chose `inner sep=0.025` and not `0` or any other number?

Comment: 0.025cm is half of 0.05cm, your wanted radius.

Comment: Oh, ok. I didn't realize the node was otherwise empty.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, scale really scales mainly distances, not line widths etc. **UPDATE**: I misread the question, sorry, and big thanks to [Paul Paulsen for pointing this out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464315/non-scalable-unit-in-tikz/464320?noredirect=1#comment1168557_464320). You can just divide out the scale factor in the circle radii.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, scale=2]
\pgfgettransformentries{\myscale}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,1);
\filldraw   (0,0) circle[radius=0.05cm/\myscale] node[anchor=north] {$P$}
            (2,1) circle[radius=0.05cm/\myscale] node[anchor=north] {$Q$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,1);
\filldraw   (0,0) circle[radius=0.05cm] node[anchor=north] {$P$}
            (2,1) circle[radius=0.05cm] node[anchor=north] {$Q$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**: Here I address how one can scale the line width with the distances. Note that I do *not* recommend using `\pgflowlevelsynccm` here as it screws up the bounding box (which is why there are `\vspace`s added), but I list it for completeness.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\subsection*{Original post}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, scale=2]
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,1);
\filldraw   (0,0) circle[radius=0.05cm] node[anchor=north] {$P$}
            (2,1) circle[radius=0.05cm] node[anchor=north] {$Q$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\subsection*{Using \texttt{\textbackslash pgflowlevelsynccm}}

\vspace*{2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, scale=2]
\pgflowlevelsynccm
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,1);
\filldraw   (0,0) circle[radius=0.05cm] node[anchor=north] {$P$}
            (2,1) circle[radius=0.05cm] node[anchor=north] {$Q$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace*{1cm}

\subsection*{Reading out transformation and applying it to lines etc.}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, scale=2]
\pgfgettransformentries{\myscale}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}
\draw[->,line width=\myscale*\pgflinewidth] (0,0) -- (2,1);
\filldraw[,line width=\myscale*\pgflinewidth]   
(0,0) circle[radius=\myscale*0.05cm] node[anchor=north] {$P$}
            (2,1) circle[radius=\myscale*0.05cm] node[anchor=north] {$Q$};
\end{tikzpicture}


\subsection*{Reading out transformation and applying it to lines etc. (2)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, scale=2]
\pgfgettransformentries{\myscale}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}
\draw[->,line width=\myscale*\pgflinewidth] (0,0) -- (2,1);
\filldraw[,line width=\myscale*\pgflinewidth]   
(0,0) circle[radius=\myscale*0.05cm] node[below=\myscale*0.05cm] {$P$}
            (2,1) circle[radius=\myscale*0.05cm] node[above=\myscale*0.05cm] {$Q$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\subsection*{Reading out transformation and applying it to lines etc. (3)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, scale=2,transform shape]
\pgfgettransformentries{\myscale}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}
\draw[->,line width=\myscale*\pgflinewidth] (0,0) -- (2,1);
\filldraw[,line width=\myscale*\pgflinewidth]   
(0,0) circle[radius=\myscale*0.05cm] node[below=\myscale*0.05cm] {$P$}
            (2,1) circle[radius=\myscale*0.05cm] node[above=\myscale*0.05cm] {$Q$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And I would draw the thing probably like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, scale=2,bullet/.style={transform shape,inner
sep=0.05cm,fill,circle}]
\pgfgettransformentries{\myscale}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}
\draw[->,shorten >=2pt,line width=\myscale*\pgflinewidth] 
(0,0) node[bullet,label=below:$P$]{}
   --         (2,1) node[bullet,label=below:$Q$]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But the OP asks how to not scale the circles, not how to scale everything...

Comment: @PaulPaulsen Very good point! Thanks a lot! (I had the opposite problem, i.e. wanted to scale the line width, some time ago, and was thinking this was asked here. But no, you are absolutely right, and I was too sloppy.)

Comment: +1, nice update and a cool way to deal with the problem :)

Comment: While having to write `/\myscale` can be a hindrance if there are many nodes, it allows not to scale any shape, so it is useful.